# Consolidate multiple views into one view without coupling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Let's say I have:

object A, B, C each with corresponding models, views, and controllers

How would you load them all into one view (site index)? You could use a partial of each model's index, but then methods of that particular controller don't get called so you would have to add that view's methods. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You mean the controller methods, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described is about all you can do.

However, methods of each model are still accessible no matter where you access that model from. Unless you're talking about helper methods. In which case you'll need add `helper :a, :b, :c` to the site index controller, so that the helper methods associated with each model are available from views and partials rendered by the site index controller.

Comment: yeah... not very DRY or not very orthogonal. Any other comments would be appreciated.